# Why don't the combat helmets appear every time the disk is taken off in Tron in a battle environment?

Tags: tron-legacy

In Tron Legacy in 'Games' when the combatant takes off his disk a helmet appears.

But when Sam goes to save Quorra, @0:40 you can see that Sam does not have the helmet.

**I am assuming that the helmet appears as a safety feature, so why does it not appear every time?**

Comment: In the second clip it looks like he still has the disc on his back, but he also has a second disc that he got from that wall. Am I missing the context here?

Answer (score 1):

I would Assume the helmet was only "loaded" for "The Games" portion inside the Grid?

My theory, is that particular feature wouldn't "load" anywhere else. So the programming only gave that edge case to "the games" portion